# Why can functions be called using `` operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
<script>
  alert`1` // outputs 1
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
  function f($a) {
    alert($a);
  }

  f`2`; // outputs 2
</script>
```

Why does JavaScript allow functions to be called using `` instead of `()`?

References like https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp mentions nothing about the use of ``.

Can `` also be used to call functions that take more than 1 argument? If so, how?

Comment: it's part of [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) that introduced backtick operator